# How to create a sectioned list view with images and string in it

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create a sectioned list view like the one shown in the image.

I have already tried the sample at

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/LabelledSections/

And used it but was not able to add image to it. How can I achieve it ?

[image]

I had to do this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how xamarin dev goes, but in normal Android world you would use an ExpandableListView to make this happen.

Comment: @JaySoyer ExpandableListView is used when you need accordion like views and this is not really the case for it.

Comment: @StevanMladenovic Yes it can be used like that but also for other cases like this. It's very easy to make it expand all groups and keep them expanded.  It's a perfect solution for creating what the OP requests.  I've done it numerous times now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making list with different item types.There are 2 things that you need to override in your adapter (apart from usual stuff): ViewTypeCount(property that only has get method and returns number of view types) and GetItemViewType(that returns an int that is unique to your view type). Then in your GetView method you can return different view depending on view type. You can still use ViewHolder pattern and such cause convertView will always be of the type you need at that moment(or null).

So now you pass a list of objects (List) and depending on type cast them to appropriate type. This way you will have a list of separator, item, item, item, separator, item, separator, item, item... Here is stripped down example of adapter.

```
public class ExampleAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private const int ItemViewTypeListItem = 0;
    private const int ItemViewTypeSeparator = 1;
    private const int ItemViewTypeCount = 2;

    private readonly Activity _context;
    private readonly List<object> _spartendaten;

    public SparendatenAdapter(Activity context, List<object> items)
    {
        _context = context;
        _spartendaten = items;
    }

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override int ViewTypeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemViewTypeCount;
        }
    }

    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return _spartendaten[position] is Separator
            ? ItemViewTypeSeparator
            : ItemViewTypeSpartendaten;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _spartendaten.Count; }
    }

    private class ViewHolder : Object
    {
        private TextView _tvTitle;
        //... separator and list item declarations

        public void Bind(Activity context, int position, object item, int itemType)
        {
            if (itemType == ItemViewTypeSeparator)
            {
                //bind your separatorview
            }
            else
            {
                //bind your 
            }

        }

        public void Initialize(View view, int itemType)
        {
            if (itemType == ItemViewTypeListItem)
            {
                //initialize list item
            }
            else
            {
                //initialize separator
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me, i'm using listview but i dont know how to add the image, tou can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289486/add-sidebar-icon-on-android-using-visual-studio-and-xamarin

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show a list of items that contains an image and some text next to it you have to provide it to the adapter.

Your list item layout, lets call it ImageTextListItem will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ListItem_Icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/ListItem_Title"
            android:text="PeopleName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And is saved in the Layout folder as ImageTextListItem.axml

In your adapter the `GetView` method looks like this:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView ?? inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ImageTextListItem, parent, false);

        var people = peopleList[position];

        var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ListItem_Title);
        var icon = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ListItem_Icon);

        name.Text = people.Name;
        icon.SetImageResource(people.Image);

        return view;
    }
```

To reach your goal you have to combine the code from your link with the code written here. This means that my ImageTextListItem replaces the ListItem.axml from the layout folder and my GetView method is the on you need to call if it is not a header.

Comment: I want to add sections like the one shown in first screen shot. And also have images and text like you have mentioned.